# Calling ajax call before Every other ajax call in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I am working on angular project. When I login to application, I am saving access_token received from the login service in to $cookies. This access_token gets expires after 2 mins. 
After login, for subsequest functionality, I have to send this access_token to the service using $http to get valid response.
Once this access_token gets expires after 2 mins, I am calling to a service which will regenerate access_token and again saving in $cookies.
Without access_token, my other functionalities won't work.

Basically I need to check if access token present in $cookies or not before every service call in the application. If access token is not present, then Need to regenerate it with another service call using $http and save it back in cookies and then the desire service call of the functionality. and If access token present then do the desire service call.

my one of functionality is :

```
mPosController.controller('offerController', ['$scope', '$route', '$cookies', '$rootScope', 'mosServiceFactory', 'ngDialog', '$modal', '$q', function ($scope, $route, $cookies, $rootScope, mosServiceFactory, ngDialog, $modal, $q) {

       mosServiceFactory.viewAllOffers('page=0').then(function (data) {
                //Do the desire functionality
            });
   }]);
```

My services are :

```
mPosServices.factory('mosServiceFactory', function ($http, $rootScope, $cookies,$q) {
    return{
        viewAllOffers: function (page) {
            var allOffers = $http({
                method: "get",
                url: "myserviceurl?enrollmentId=" + $rootScope.enrollMentId + "&" + page + "&size=10&access_token=" + $cookies.get('access_token'),
            });
            return allOffers;
        },
        refresh_token: function () {
            var refreshToken = $http({
                method: "get",
                url: "myserviceurl/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=restapp&client_secret=restapp&refresh_token=" + $cookies.get('refresh_token'),
            })
            return refreshToken;
        },
 }
});
```

So before calling viewAllOffers(), I need to check if access_token is present in $cookies or not if not thencall refresh_token service.

How do I achieve this generically?

Comment: You can try with  `request` interceptors in `$http` service, [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is some documentation, scroll down to **Interceptor** part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically I need to check if access token present in $cookies or not
>   before every service call in the application. If access token is not
>   present, then Need to regenerate it..
>
> .. How do I achieve this generically?

You can simply create an  `interceptor` to check if the `access_token` exists in cookies before making **any** `$http` call. You would need to add use `$injector` to get `mosServiceFactory` instance inside of interceptor.

```
mPosServices.service('APIInterceptor', ['$injector', '$cookies', function($injector, $cookies) {
    var service = this;
    service.request = function(config) {
        if (!$cookies.get('access_token') && config.url.indexOf('myservice/oauth/token?grant_type=') === -1) {
            return $injector.get('mosServiceFactory').refresh_token().then(function(response) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (response.data.expiresIn * 1000));
                $cookies.remove('access_token');
                $cookies.put('access_token', response.data.value, {
                    expires: date
                });
                $cookies.put('refresh_token', response.data.refreshToken.value);
            }).then(function() {
                return config; // <-- token is refreshed, reissue original request
            });
        }
        return config;
    };

    service.responseError = function(response) {
        return response;
    };
}]);
```

`APIInterceptor` will monitor all requests made with the `$http` service, perform pre-requisite operations (*like regenerating access_token*) and intercept any response errors.

You would need to push the interceptor to `$httpProvider` in your `config` function.

```
module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('sessionInjector');
}]);
```

EDIT: Since the request to `refresh_token` is also making use of `$http` service, you would get a circular dependency error. This is because every time you find `$cookies.get('access_token')` empty, the interceptor will try to get a new token from `mosServiceFactory.refresh_token()` which again will bring interceptor into play. To avoid this, you need to make a check within `APIInterceptor` to let the request proceed if `grant_type !='refresh_token'`

Comment: I am doing exactly same thing as shown above in code , But  I am getting error as 

**"Circular dependency found: $http <- mosServiceFactory <- APIInterceptor <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile"**

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: @Rahul: Yes I missed it. You were getting the circular dependency error because `APIInterceptor` calls `mosServiceFactory.refresh_token` whenever it doesnt find the access_token. since Interceptors act as a middleware in all request/response cycles it tries to call `refresh_token` even if the $http request is being made from refresh_token itself. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: ohh yes..now I understand why I am getting this error, but does config object has grand_type property ? or we need to set this property for each $http call, so that It can be captured in interceptor?

Comment: You yourself are setting it in the `refresh_token()` request URL. `url: "myserviceurl/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token..`

Comment: Ohh sorry , My bad... I tried ,but config.grant_type is not working, went through angular https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http docs, I found config object has params property, but its returning undefined. I am not able to check grant_type as url param

Comment: You should follow the right syntax. `$http.get(<URL>,<OPTIONS>)`

Comment: `$http.get("myserviceurl/oauth/token",{'grant_type':'refresh_token','client_id':‌​'restapp','client_secret':'restapp','refresh_token':$cookies.get('refresh_token')‌​})`

Comment: Where options is in json format. For http GET requests, it will be passed as query_string

Comment: actually once I inject mosServiceFactory in my service above, i get circular dependency error. Even I tried manually injecting using $injector, but still getting same error.

Comment: @Rahul: Updated the code. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31066786/1379667) asnwer for details.

Comment: @Rahul: Feel Free to upvote/accept if this helped in any way. That'll allow other people to rectify similar issues in future :)